# Sentences starting with "No matter how he"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Is the following grammatically correct?
No matter how he kept tossing and turning, he could not fall asleep.

If grammatically correct, is it different in meaning to:
No matter how he tossed and turned, he could not fall asleep.

Comment: Both are possibly grammatical - but do they make sense? "Tossing and turning" is not normally a strategy for achieving sleep - it is a more a symptom of sleeplessness.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possibly grammatical - but do they make sense? "Tossing and turning" is not normally a strategy for achieving sleep - it is a more a symptom of sleeplessness.

However ***No matter how hard he tried he could not fall asleep*** would be both grammatical and logical.